# angular2 with restful service

Tags: web-services, angular, angular2-services, restful-url

I am trying RESTful service with my Angular2 application. 
It is working when I give local json url `(/app/config.json)`. But it is not working when I try with below url.

URL : `http://localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/json/metallica/get`

The above url will return json value as below,

```ts
{
  "title": "SingerName",
  "singer": "Singer123",
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Hero123"
}
```

**app.module**

```ts
@NgModule({  
  declarations: [  AppComponent,HeroListComponent,HeroDetailComponent],        
  imports: [BrowserModule,HttpModule,routing],  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**HeroService.ts**

```ts
getHeroes(){ 
  var headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }); 
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); 
  return this._http.request("localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/‌​json/metallica/…) .map((res:Response) => res.json()); 
}
```

**HeroListComponent**

```ts
@Component({  
   selector: 'my-hero-detail',  
   template: `
      <h2>Hero List Component</h2>  
      <ul *ngFor="let hero of heroes">  
         {{hero}}  
        <li>{{hero.id}}</li>  
        <li>{{hero.name}}</li>  
     </ul>`  
})
export class HeroListComponent implements  OnInit {  
  heroes = []; 

  constructor(private _heroService:HeroService) {}  

  ngOnInit(){    
    this._heroService.getHeroes().
       .subscribe(response =>this.heroes = response);    
      }    
  }
```

Comment: You can't enter relative paths like that in a rest request.

Comment: Does the rest link works, if you open it in the browser directly?

Comment: Yes that rest link is working in browser/postman client.

Comment: Thanks @echonax. The can I call that url by using request method like this._http.request ?

Comment: @Santhoshkumar here's an example plunker for getting a json file with an http request: http://plnkr.co/edit/60E2qb9gOjvkEAeR5CtE?p=info. If it helps you I can provide it as an answer.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar any errors in console?

Comment: @echonax Already I am trying with that example only. It is working fine. In that example they are using json object. But I am using Restful Service request. Pls suggest some ideas to request option from rest service.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar I don't understand what's not working. `"./assets/herolist.json` or `http://localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/json/metallica/get`

Comment: @AJT_82 There is no error in console. Values will display, if I use json object. Values are blank, if I use  http://localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/json/metallica/get url.

Comment: @echonax : Below url is not working. http://localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/json/metallic‌​a/get

Comment: @Santhoshkumar can you show your code where you use this method?

Comment: @echonax: Please find the method. getHeroes(){
var headers = new Headers({
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http.request("http://localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/json/metallica/get",options)
.map((res:Response) => res.json());
}

Comment: @Santhoshkumar ok but where/how do you use `getHeroes`? Please edit your question and add it there, it's hard to read from the comment section.

Comment: @Santhoshkumar I've added a `.` before subscribe but I think it was a typo. Can you also add the template where you use `heroes`?

Comment: @echonax I added the template in question.

Comment: Have you tried the safe navigation operator like '{{hero?.name}}'?

Comment: @echonax : Thank you for your advice. It is working with safe navigation operator like '{{heroes?.name}}'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what is returned is:

```
{ "title": "SingerName", "singer": "Singer123", "id": "1", "name": "Hero123" }
```

This means this is an Object, and not an array you can iterate through in your template.

So maybe change the variable name to just hero, since it's an object and not an array, but this is just a detail ;) Here I'll use `heroes` though:

```
ngOnInit(){    
  this._heroService.getHeroes().
     subscribe(response => this.heroes = response);    
}
```

Then you do not need to iterate the response, just display it like so:

```
<div>
  {{heroes?.id}}
  {{heroes?.name}}
</div>
```

And it's useful to use the safe navigation operator :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. It is working with safe navigation operator <div>
  {{heroes?.id}}
  {{heroes?.name}}
</div>.

Comment: You are very welcome! Yes, the safe navigation operator is a wonderful thing in the async world of angular :D Have a great evening/night and happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

as [echonax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5706293/echonax) said don't use relative paths and  set header like this :

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this._http.get("/assets/herolist.json", options ).map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: Thank you Bougarfaoui. The /assets/herolist.json is already working. I need to connect REST services like 'http://localhost:8082/RESTful_Jersey_JSON/rest/json/metallica/get'.